spring return xml pojo class with request
I keep getting a HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable. The only thing that works is a string. I am using spring 5 and java 11
Here is my @RestController where i am trying to return an xml of a POJO class
 @RestController
public class GetCountries extends AbstractResource  {
    private final CountriesToCountryLinksTransformer countryLinksTransformer = new CountriesToCountryLinksTransformer();


    @RequestMapping(value = "/service", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<CountryLinks> getCountries() throws JAXBException {
        setDefaultRequestAuditingAttributes();
        List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<>(getAuthorized().getAvailableCountries());
        CountryLinks countries = countryLinksTransformer.transform(countryList, uriInfo, request.getRequestURL());

      request.setAttribute(RequestConstants.SUCCESS_STATUS, true);

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

       return new ResponseEntity<>(countries, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

    }`


here is the POJO

`@XmlRootElement(name = "countryLinks")
public class CountryLinks  {

    @XmlElement(name = "countryLink")
    private List<Link> countries = null;

    public CountryLinks() {
        countries = new ArrayList<Link>();
    }

    public void addCountry(Link country) {
        countries.add(country);
    }

    public List<Link> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void setCountries(List<Link> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }
}


Response should look like
<media:countryLinks xmlns:media="urn:media.services" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<countryLink xl:href="http://localhost:8080/Media/service/US" xl:type="locator">US</countryLink>
<countryLink xl:href="http://localhost:8080/Media/service/CA" xl:type="locator">CA</countryLink>
</media:countryLinks>


when i convert to string it look like
<countryLinks>
<countries>
<href>http://localhost:8080/Media/service/US</href>
<type>locator</type>
<val>US</val>
</countries>
<countries>
<href>http://localhost:8080/Media/service/CA</href>
<type>locator</type>
<val>CA</val>
</countries>
</countryLinks>


here is my servlet.xml

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/xml" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />


    <!--    <bean id="stringConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">-->



<!--    <bean id="xmlConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter">-->
<!--        <property name="supportedMediaTypes">-->
<!--            <list>-->
<!--                <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">-->
<!--                    <constructor-arg index="0" value="text" />-->
<!--                    <constructor-arg index="1" value="xml" />-->
<!--                    <constructor-arg index="2" value="UTF-8" />-->
<!--                </bean>-->
<!--            </list>-->
<!--        </property>-->
<!--    </bean>-->
    
    <!-- Exception Resolver -->
<!--    <bean id="exceptionMessageAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver"/>-->
<!--    -->
<!--    &lt;!&ndash; Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">-->
<!--        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />-->
<!--    </bean>-->

    <bean id="xmlMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/xml" />
    </bean>


</beans>

im not sure why this isnt working. Any one know what i can do to return the xml pojo in the response?

The HTTP 406 Not Acceptable error occurs when a server is unable to fulfill a client's request because the requested resource is not available in the acceptable content types specified in the client's request. To resolve this issue, the client should adjust the Accept header in their request.
You need add header request for client - Accept: application/xml
